# javascript: does onsubmit only execute when it detects a "return false" 

Tags: javascript, html

i dont quite understand how the `onsubmit="return validate()"` works.
why do i have to `return` the function? does this work only when it detects a `return false` from the statement?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        if ((document.example2.naming.value == "") || (document.example2.feed.value == "")) {
            alert("You must fill in all of the required .fields!");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
</script>

<form name="example2" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="submit" name="B1" value="Submit">​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Check your assumptions again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `return` for `onsubmit` determines whether the form actually submits or not (`true` or `false`, respectively). This is useful for Javascript when you want to do something specific before allowing the form to submit or not. For example, like the code you provided, the point is to stop the form from submitting if the form isn't valid - if a certain field is blank. The important part is that you need to include `return` in the onsubmit part, as well as actually returning `true` or `false` in the function you call. This is because the behavior for `onsubmit` is to always complete unless you return `false`. So when you do something like:

```
onsubmit="validate();"
```

nothing is returned (because of the lack of `return`) - so the function is run but that's it, so the form is submitted. When you add `return`, then the submitting depends on the return value - what's returned from the function. If you don't use `return`, it doesn't matter what the `validate` function returns, because the result of `validate` is not actually returned to `onsubmit`.

Answer (score 1):

When `return`ing `false`, you *prevent* the `form` from being submitted. Otherwise, the form would be submitted, even though it may have validation errors, e.g., the `feed` value was empty.

On the other hand, if you `return true`, the form data will be submitted to the URL defined by the [`action`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) attribute.