# form action not calling script php

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

Edit: calling the script works but still having a problem with passing my parameters.

here is processdonateditems.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {

    $scripttype =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);

    if($scripttype == "cancel") {
              ....
```

here are my buttons which have to submit this form

```
<input type="button" value="Confirm Sent" class="btn" <?php if($fetch_donate3['claim_status']=='1'){?> enabled <?php } else {?> disabled <?php }?>>

 <input type="button" value="Cancel Donation" class="btn")
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Are you posting `id` & `type` parameters?

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="id" />` similarly for type?

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons have *type="button"*. If you want some of them to submit the form they should contain

```
type="submit"
```

If that's not the case then use javascript to submit the form like that:

```
document.getElementById("change_donate").submit();
```

Edit:

to receive $_POST['id'] and $_POST['type'] you need to have those elements inside the form. Like that for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="" />
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help changing to type="submit" made it call the script

Comment: but im still getting an error in my logic for the POST parameters it isn't seeing isset(id) isset(type)

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['type'])) { this is false.

Comment: I just edited my question. You need to add those *id* and *type* elements inside the form.

Comment: okay i added that, but in my logic i want to do 2 things differently when type is entered on cancel call a different block of code, when type is process do a different block of code...how do i set the type POST parameters JUST on button click

Comment: @Krasimir why hidden?

Comment: will calling onclick in the buttons still submit the form after the onclick method is called?

Comment: @user2127136 you need to add a radio button, and check it's value on the php side, and process accordingly..

Comment: If you leave the buttons with *type="button"* then you will need javascript to submit the form. If you leave the *type="submit"* pair in some of the buttons then you should use another method similar to the one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449051/javascript-does-onsubmit-only-execute-when-it-detects-a-return-false

Comment: why can't i change the parameters on different buttons its easier and more aesthetically pleasing

Comment: @bio: I have no idea what he is trying to do with those fields. I guess that id is a hidden thing.

Comment: during the form submit you can't add data to the buttons and send it. You should use other html elements like input, select, textarea.

Comment: So Im trying to make 2 distinct things happen when the 2 buttons are pressed but all the code is in 1 script. how do i change the type parameters dynamically on click?

Comment: @Krasimir the question is unclear..the op should google these stuff rather than asking as these are just basics..

Comment: @user2127136 that is what radio buttons are for..please try using google a bit more..