# Routing after Sign In on Firebase

Tags: javascript, error-handling, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So this is my attempt to edit my previous post after going at it for another two days and doing some trial and error.

To be more specific, what I need help with is routing to a specific page based on the emails that are typed in or the Admin ID. Right now after you sign in and firebase authenticates that you have an account in the database the while loops at the bottom of this function set in and you are taken to the right maps.

However if you sign in with a email that does not exist in the database then the error handling will alert an error but it can't do much more then that. IT can't do what I need it to do which is to break or return and just stop the function - I am assuming it cant do that because its scope doesn't allow it to effect the entire function. I have tried putting the while loops inside the conditionals that are in the error handling but that didnt seem to do anything as when i try to sign in nothing happens. I even tried using a variable to add (+1) and then if its more then 0 to not run the while loops but then i remembered that the scope of the error handling wont actually change global variables cause it doesnt have access to that.

This is driving me crazy - i just need the dam code to not run the while loops if an errorCode or errorMessage comes up. Please lords of code bestow upon me some guidance.

Code as it stands...

```
<!-- <a ="btn-signup" href="#signup">sign up </a> -->
  <div class="btn-signin" id="btn-signin">
  <form action="javascript: submitform()" method="get" id="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="emailInput" placeholder="Enter School Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Enter Password">  
    <input type="text" name="uniqueID" id="myAdminID" placeholder="Admin ID *if applicable*">
    <input type="submit" id="emailSubmit" value="Submit">     
  </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Routing based on email ending "@fordham.edu" -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform() {
      var email_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("email").value;
      var password_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("password").value;
      var adminID = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("uniqueID").value;          

      if ((email_input.indexOf('.edu') >= 0) && (password_input.length > 4)) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email_input, password_input).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          if(errorCode === "auth/user-not-found") {
              alert("User does not exist - go ahead and sign up first");                  
          } else if(errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
              alert("You might have the wrong password, try again");
          }          
          // ...
        });                
      } else if ((adminID.indexOf('GJGBING') >= 0) && (password_input.length > 4)) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email_input, password_input).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          if(errorCode === "auth/user-not-found") {
              alert("User does not exist - go ahead and sign up first");
          } else if(errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
              alert("You might have the wrong password, try again");
          }                    
          // ...
        });                 
      } else {
        alert("Please use a .edu email address or enter your unique Admin ID");
        return;
      }; 


      var schools = ["@fordham.edu", "@sjsu.edu"];
      var mapLocations = ["#select-a-machine", "#select-a-machine"];
      var adminIdLocation = ["#select-a-machine"]
      var adminIDs = ["GJGBING"]        
      var i = 0;
      var a = 0;

      while (a < adminIDs.length) {
          if (adminID.indexOf(adminIDs[a]) >= 0) {
              window.location.assign(adminIdLocation[a]);
              break;
          } else if (adminID.indexOf(adminIDs[a]) < 0) {
              a++;
          }
      };


      while (i < schools.length) {
          if(email_input.indexOf(schools[i]) >= 0) {
              window.location.assign(mapLocations[i]);
              break;
          } else if(email_input.indexOf(schools[i]) < 0) {
              i++;
          }
      };

      if(i >= schools.length && (email_input.indexOf('.edu') >= 0)) {
          alert("We are currently not at your school");
      };

    };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
return;
```

break doesn't work when nested within two levels of conditionals. Here is the test I used to prove it:

```
function test(){
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i >= 5){
        console.log("great than five");
        while(i == 5){
            break;  
            console.log("break stops this conditional loop the function");
        }
    }
}
    console.log("this will execute");
}
```

Where as compared to this usage of return it kills the entire function:

```
    function test(){
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i >= 5){
        console.log("great than five");
        while(i == 5){
            return;  
            console.log("return kills this function, this won't log");
        }
    }
}
    console.log("this won't execute");
}
```

Comment: where should i put - i placed it inside the conditional that activates if there is an error thrown? I tried placing it before and after the alert but on both cases when i try to submit the form it does nothing. In the console I see two errors relating to it; a "submitform is not defined" and a Uncaught SyntaxErrror: Unexpected token.

Comment: I tested this out and I'm going to edit my answer, that thread was wrong in saying that would work.  A simple return should work as the lower answer showed.  break isn't working in the way you have the code because it is nested within two levels of conditionals. But I made a test that I will edit above to show you it working.

Comment: So i added the return to my code (check it out in the original post) but the problem is that when the credentials are correct its not doing anything at all. It wont alert an error message or code or even route. however if the user doesnt exist it will alert with an error message and stay where it is which is a positive. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you put the full code that you are using up so that I can test it? This part doesn't function as a stand alone because it doesn't have the firebase part.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant put up any more of the code as its sensitive information for work but if all you need is the firebase to test it you can just grab the SDK from a firebase if you have it and paste it at the top. If you need more then that I dont think it would matter then cause I have CSS and HTML and all these other js files that i would need to upload in order to see everything.

Comment: i dont no if it will help but i see "errorCode not defined" in the console

Answer (score 0):

if this function is used an an onSubmit function, then you should add the following line at the desired location

```
return false;
```

to prevent form submission. See [javascript: does onsubmit only execute when it detects a "return false"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449051/javascript-does-onsubmit-only-execute-when-it-detects-a-return-false)  for more information

**EDIT 1:**
I think your problem is, that the error-function your are adding to the execution of signInWithEmailAndPassword() is being executed by firebase in case an error occurs. As you see the message telling you to sign up, the reload action has already taken place. You can add an alert which displays 
the error message and code provided by firebase.

If you want to stop submission in this case, remove the location.reload in the if statement and check the value of errorCode in the line just before the else if

```
     });
     if (errorCode) {
        return false;
     }
  } else if (adminID.indexOf('GJGBING') >= 0) {
```

Comment: I edited the original post to show the html that it is linked too

Comment: as I wrote, I'd recommend <action .... onSubmit="return submitform()" > and using `return false;` when you want to abort submission anywhere in your submitform function

Comment: thanks for explaining that - unfortunately it didnt seem to work. the same thing happened. the alert was fired telling me that i should sign up and then i was routed to a different location

Comment: did you remove the function from the action, e.g  `<form action="blank.html" method="get" id="myForm" onSubmit="return submitform()">`? At what line did you enter the `return false;`?

Comment: no i did not haha - ok so i tried that I changed it, e.g <form action="index.html" method="get" id="myForm" onSubmit="return submitform()"> . Upon testing a user that did not exist it worked, it didn't route the form and just alerted me with the right message. Problem is this though - once i tried it with a user that did exist and the correct password, it throws the alert that is inside the conditional and then proceeds to route to the correct location as it should do if someone signs in with the correct credentials. Any idea why the alert is being triggered yet it correctly proceeds to route?

Comment: You can add alerts to see the values and understand the flow of logic.

Comment: Hey so i edited the code in my first post to show how the code looks as of right now - upon using the alerts to push out firebases error messages things look good for when you do the wrong credentials. However now upon submitting the correct credentials nothing happens at all, no alert pops up and  i am not routed anywhere. Thanks for all your help so far btw man really appreciate it.

Comment: I keep seeing "errorCode not defined" in the console as the only error relating to this part - dont no if that does anything to help

Comment: The variable needs to defined on a global level. Currently it's only defined in the function. If you can't get it to work with variables, you can, as a fallback, set the value in a dom element and get it from there after the call.